# How can I use a character as index in R?

Tags: r, list, vector, dataframe, character

I currently have characters like "361:372" or "c(325, 326, 327, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348)", and I'm trying to use these as indices.

In other words, Is there a way to convert a character "361:372" to a vector c(361:372), or from "c(325, 326)" to c(325, 326)? I intend to use them as indices in a data frame, such as df[c(325, 326),].

Thank you so much for your time

Comment: You can try: `eval(parse(text = "361:372"))`

Comment: Thank you so much! This totally solves the first problem. However I actually have the two formats mixed together, would there be a way to convert from "c(1, 2)" to c(1, 2) as well? I tried eval("c(1, 2)") but this would just return a character

Comment: `eval(parse(text = "c(1, 2)"))` will return the result of c(1,2), i.e 1 and 2.

Comment: Oh wow didn't realise. Thank you Haboryme, this really helped!